# Como adicionar caracter depois da ultima palavra escrita na linha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Prezada comunidade,

Estou com uma duvida que já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo resolver.

Tenho uma lista de nomes ex;

```
José Mario da Silva
Mariana Cristina
William Caio
Jorge Luiz Campos de Silva Andrade
```

No caso são mais de 2000 nomes... o que tenho que fazer é depois da ultima palavra digitada tenho que colocar 50 caracter de "                    " vazios e depois do ultimo vazio inserir mais 15 caracter "000000000000000"... para inserir eu estava usando a seguinte formula ex:

```
=CONCATENAR(A1;"                        ";"000000000000000")
```

Meu grande problema é que as linhas estão ficando desalinhadas, por conta que cada nome tem uma quantidade de caracter... no caso deveria ficar assim:

```
José Mario da Silva                      000000000000000
Mariana Cristina                         000000000000000
William Caio                             000000000000000
Jorge Luiz Campos de Silva Andrade       000000000000000
```

Mas está ficando desde modo:

```
José Mario da Silva                      000000000000000
Mariana Cristina                     000000000000000
William Caio                   00000000000000
Jorge Luiz Campos de Silva Andrade                   000000000000000
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar neste caso, pois não sei mas o que fazer.

Comment: Não entendi. Parece obvio que fiquem desalinhadas, já que o numero de caracteres brancos e 0 são fixos e o comprimento dos nomes são variáveis.

Comment: Exato, gostaria que todas estejam alinhadas, existe a possibilidade?

Comment: O numero de brancos pode variar?

Comment: O numero de caracter total é de 212, mas dos 212 o nome tambem entra nessa contagem... os valores de zero são sempre de 15 caracteres.

Comment: Pode fazer um numero variável de espaços utilizando a formula `REPETIR` e a formula `NÚM.CARACT` mas não vai alinhar porque há letras mais largas que outras

Comment: Então... tentei isso também e não alinhou mesmo... eu precisava alinhar eles.

Comment: Mas não vai alinhar visualmente no excel, porque se exportar para ficheiro se for lido em texto fica alinhado. Você vai utilizar isso onde?

Comment: Em txt mesmo, mas quando converto ele não alinha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Excel Fórmula

#### Com célula extra de referência

Insira esta fórmula em alguma célula `=MÁXIMO((NÚM.CARACT($A:$A)))`, por exemplo `Z1` e aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (lembre de selecionar cada célula e pressionar os botões após inserir matrizes em fórmulas, por exemplo A:A)

E usar esta fórmula: `=A1&REPT("*";($Z$1-NÚM.CARACT(A1))+50)&"000000000000000"`

#### Sem célula extra de referência

Ou sem o Z1 `=A1&REPT("*";(MÁXIMO((NÚM.CARACT($A$1:$A$2000)))-NÚM.CARACT(A1))+50)&"000000000000000"` Porém, sugiro utilizar a fórmula anterior, pois você só precisará apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> na célula de referência `Z1`

Este é o resultado, alterando a fonte, para uma fonte monoespaçada é possível visualizar, alterei para `*` para ver melhor. Nos testes são colocados somente 15 asteriscos

[image: Resultado]

## Excel VBA

### Inserir a fórmula e autofill por VBA

Assumindo os dados na coluna A e os novos dados na B, insira a fórmula desejada em B1 e execute este código para Autofill em B.

```
lrA = Planilha1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
Planilha1.Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Planilha1.Range("B1:B" & lrA)
```

### VBA

Ia fazer um código, mas acabei nem fazendo pois com Excel fórmula o problema já foi resolvido. Porém caso deseje, a mesma lógica é feita em VBA. Podendo ser utilizado a função Len e loops. E para escrever um .txt, este [link](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/read-write-utf8/)

Answer (score 1):

Verifique qual é o maior comprimento de nome que você tem em sua tabela 
e substitua o número 50 dessa formula por ele.

A1 é a celula onde estão escritos os nomes, no meu exemplo:

```
=CONCATENAR(A1;REPT(" ";50-NÚM.CARACT(A1));"!00000000000000")
```

No excel com essa formula ele não parece direito, mas se eu copiar o conteudo das celulas e colar em editor de textos com caracteres de tamanho não variavel  fica certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tentei cada um dos códigos acima, funcionaram mas mesmo assim, não sei o por que quando eu inseria no txt ficavam desalinhados.

Depois de um certo tempo quebrando a cabeça e com ajuda do programador Anderson, chegamos neste código que atende todas as especificações;

```html
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()

Dim iArq As Long
Dim NOME As String
Dim op As Variant
Dim linha As Long
Dim resposta As String
   
linha = 1
While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Concluidos").Cells(linha, 1) <> ""

NOME = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Concluidos").Cells(linha, 1)
      
While Len(NOME) < 50
           
NOME = NOME + " "
            
Wend
NOME = NOME & "000000000000000"
       
iArq = FreeFile

Open fileELEB For Append As iArq

Print #iArq, NOME

Close #iArq
linha = linha + 1
Wend
    
MsgBox "O arquivo foi exportado com sucesso! ", vbInformation, "Exportar arquivos"

resposta = MsgBox("Você gostaria voltar ao menu?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "QNIS - CAIXA")
    
If resposta = vbYes Then

    
Else

Workbooks("QNIS V3.xlsm").Close False
Unload FormQNIS
End If

End Sub
```

Quero agradecer desde já a ajuda de todos, muito obrigado!!!